# How to use ExtJs 4.2.1 htmlEditor in sencha touch 2.3.1?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to create a htmlEditor in sencha touch 2 using ExtJs 4.2.1 htmlEditor, is it possible or not? If it possible then how?

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to use an ExtJS Component in Sencha Touch, because the namespace, methods, params... are different, so I would say it is not possible.

Currently you can use ExtJS 5 which supports touch and has two touch themes.

Comment: Simon i am new to sencha so could you post any example or link about same.

Comment: Checkout this example which shows ExtJS5 in a touch theme: http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/kitchensink/?theme=neptune-touch#all